# Bash correct syntax to get first 2 letters of string and make them uppercase

Tags: bash

I know I can do what I asked in the title by doing this:

```
input=abcd
input=${input^^} #makes uppercase
echo ${input:0:2} #gets first two letters
```

I wanted to know what's the correct syntax for performing both of these operations in a single line?

Comment: I don't think it exists. For the most part, the various parameter-expansion operators don't stack.

Comment: I concur with chepner. Bash can't really do complex string manipulation compactly. What you wrote is what I would write (maybe reversed so as not to waste time capitalizing letters that are to be discarded).

Comment: You can do that in gnu-sed or awk i.e. `sed 's/^\(..\).*/\U\1/' <<< "$input"` or `tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]' <<< "${input:0:2}"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```sh
declare -u input=abcd
echo "${input:0:2}"
```

See [`declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) in the manual.

This doesn't do *precisely* what you asked for

> get first 2 letters of string and make them uppercase

Instead it makes the value uppercase *then* gets the first 2 letters.

Answer (score 1):

Without declaring an array, using only parameter expansion:

```
echo $( a=abcd; b=${a:0:2} && echo ${b^^} )
```

Where:

`b=${a:0:2}` is taking substring

`${b^^}` is capitalizing that substring; echo (within command substitution) returnes it

echo (first) prints on the screen

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.